# p:commandButton not working when set its type as submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, commandbutton

I have a form. Inside the form, I have a datatable. Below you may find my code:

```
<p:column headerText="Extra request">
    <p:commandButton id="requestDetailsButton" value="details" type="button"
                     update="detailPanel"
                     action="#{enbBean.sendEnbDetailsRequest(selectedEnbData.eNbAddress)}"
                     onclick="enbDetailsDialog.show()">

        <f:setPropertyActionListener id="rowSelected" value="a" target="#{enbBean.selectedEnbData}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

The problem is that I need to set the command button with `type=submit`. But when I do this then the entire page breaks. Why it breaks and how could I overcome this problem?

Comment: You may try to remove type="button" and change "onclick" to "oncomplete" if you want your dialog to be shown after the action is completed.

Comment: If i remove type="button" then the entire page breaks and nothing is displayed. This is my problem...

Comment: Is it happening after you clicking on the button? Maybe there is something wrong with your action? Also as I know f:setPropertyActionListener doesn't have id property

Comment: No it happens when i remove the type="button". When i remove this tag then it breaks with the next refresh

Comment: Action cannot take any params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
<p:commandButton id="requestDetailsButton" value="details"
                 update="detailPanel"
                 action="#{enbBean.sendEnbDetailsRequest}"
                 oncomplete="enbDetailsDialog.show()">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="a" target="#{enbBean.selectedEnbData}" />
</p:commandButton>

public void sendEnbDetailsRequest() {
    ...
}
```

setPropertyActionListener will set #{enbBean.selectedEnbData} before action is called

Or you may try something like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="requestDetailsButton" value="details"
                 update="detailPanel"
                 actionListener="#{enbBean.sendEnbDetailsRequest}"
                 oncomplete="enbDetailsDialog.show()">
    <f:attribute name="selectedEnbData" value="a"/>
</p:commandButton>

public void sendEnbDetailsRequest(ActionEvent ae) {
    String selectedEnbData = (String)ae.getComponent().getAttributes().get("selectedEnbData");
    ...
}
```